# Why Sending Multipart/form-data is not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, react-native, multipartform-data

I am trying to send a binary file with JSON content,I am sending `user.id`, `user.type`, `file_name` and the `photo(user-logo)`.
I tried to follow many examples similar to this https://github.com/g6ling/React-Native-Tips/tree/master/How_to_upload_photo%2Cfile_in%20react-native

**basically the implementation on the client side(react-native)**

- button to select image.
- crop image using `react-native-image-crop-picker`
- upload the croppied image to api using `apisauce`

**Code**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import ImagePicker from "react-native-image-crop-picker"
import FormData from "form-data"
import { create } from "apisauce"

const EditProfile = props => {
  let [progress, setProgress] = useState(0)

   ...
   const pickImage = () => {
      ImagePicker.openPicker({
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        ...,
      }).then(image => {
        var form = new FormData()
        form.append("photoable_type", "User")
        form.append("photoable_id", user.id)
        form.append("photo_name", image.filename)
        form.append("photo",{
          name: image.filename,
          uri: image.path,
          contentType: image.mime,
        })

        const api = create({
            baseURL: baseURL,
            headers: {
               ...authHeaders,
               Accept: "application/json",
               "Content-Disposition": "form-data"
            },
        })

        api.post("/photos", form, {
            onUploadProgress: e => {
               console.log("=====================", e)
               let pro = e.loaded / e.total
               progress = pro
               console.log(progress)
               setProgress(progress)
             },
        })
        .then(res => console.log("-----------res : "))
        .catch(e => {
          console.log("submitting form Error ", e)
        })
      })

      return <Button onPress={() => pickImage()}><Text>Add Photo</Text></Button>
    }
```

**On API side using `ruby-rails`**

```
 def photo_params
    params.permit(:photoable_type, :photoable_id, :photo, :photo_name) 
 end
```

I am getting the request as

```
 Parameters: {"_parts"=>[["photoable_type", "User"], ["photoable_id", 2], ["photo_name", "IMG_0002.JPG"], ["photo", {"name"=>"IMG_0002.JPG", "uri"=>"path to /tmp/react-native-image-crop-picker/1DCB87D6-2FF5-4630-90FB-A395DE80396E.jpg", "contentType"=>"image/jpeg"}]], "photo"=>{}}
```

where `"Content-Type"=>"application/json",` by default, change it to `"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"`, I receive params like this

```
Parameters: {"{\"_parts\":"=>{"\"photoable_type\",\"User\""=>{","=>{"\"photoable_id\",2"=>{","=>{"\"photo_name\",\"IMG_0002.JPG\""=>{","=>{"\"photo\",{\"name\":\"IMG_0002.JPG\",\"uri\":\"path to tmp/react-native-image-crop-picker/B2EE6B17-50C6-4296-AFD9-D9834B374EA3.jpg\",\"contentType\":\"image/jpeg\"}"=>{"}"=>nil}}}}}}}}}
```

Am I missing something,

Comment: If you send "multipart/form-data" the server expects is a set of normal key-value form data split into parts. With "application/json" the server just expects the payload of the request to contain ONLY json data. Pick one approach or the other. Not both. You can't just sprinkle some json on top of your multipart/form-data" request and expect Rack to parse it which is whats happening with `form.append("photo",{...})`

Comment: Instead you need to add inputs like `form.append("photo[name]", somevalue); form.append("photo[url]", image.path)` which Rack will parse as a hash. https://codefol.io/posts/How-Does-Rack-Parse-Query-Params-With-parse-nested-query/

Comment: thank you @max for replying, I tried what you suggested, but in the dev console, network tab the request body send as **Request Payload** with this `[object Object]` as data, when I should see a **FormData** type,  change the form data as 


```form.append("photoable_type", "User")
        form.append("photoable_id", user.id)
        form.append("photo_name", image.filename)
        form.append("photo[name]", image.filename)
        form.append("photo[uri]", image.path)
        form.append("photo[contentType]", image.mime)```